# The new top bar gets crowded — too crowded to the point of things overlapping

Tags: bug, design

Observe:

[image]

The Winter Bash and the flags overlap. Now, I understand this is a complete edge case, and I also understand that it's a (not-so-)subtle hint that I should be handling those flags and suggested edits *pronto* if I want to get to the hats, and I also understand that the hats will soon be gone anyway. Yada yada. Still an issue, so I'm reporting.

(Plus it's a result of a recent change to a recent change, as originally the suggested edits were not displayed in the new top bar, so perhaps this possible overlap was overlooked.)

There *is* some empty room to the right of the badges, after all, so perhaps stuff can be moved just a notch in that direction.

Comment: The joys of being a mod _and_ a high rep user :)

Comment: That's a nicely drawn freehand circle. I must upvote now.

Comment: Oh noes! Indeed it is. Voting to close myself. (Edit: on the plus side, perhaps this will help some people get their Passed Judgements.)

Comment: Why the useless search box is so long, I just don't get it.